# Flat shading in LibGDX

Tags: 3d, libgdx

I am currently working on a simple game and I would like to my terrain to be flat shaded. My terrain currently looks like the following:
[image: my terrain]

As you can see the colours blend toghether depending on the vertice colours.

I would love for my end product to resemble the following:
[image: Goal]

So I was wondering how can I achieve this? What are the steps to go from gouraud shading to flat shading?

Here is how I go about creating the vertices I give to my mesh:

```
public TerrainChunk() {
    buildHeightmap();
    buildIndices();
    buildVertices();
    calcNormals(indices, vertices);

}   

public void buildHeightmap() {...}

private void buildIndices() {
    int idx = 0;
    short pitch = (short) (width + 1);
    short i1 = 0;
    short i2 = 1;
    short i3 = (short) (1 + pitch);
    short i4 = pitch;

    short row = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < height; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            indices[idx++] = i1;
            indices[idx++] = i2;
            indices[idx++] = i3;

            indices[idx++] = i3;
            indices[idx++] = i4;
            indices[idx++] = i1;

            i1++;
            i2++;
            i3++;
            i4++;
        }

        row += pitch;
        i1 = row;
        i2 = (short) (row + 1);
        i3 = (short) (i2 + pitch);
        i4 = (short) (row + pitch);
    }
}

public void buildVertices() {
    int heightPitch = height + 1;
    int widthPitch = width + 1;
    int idx = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < widthPitch; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < heightPitch; z++) {

            // POSITION
            vertices[idx++] = scale * x;
            vertices[idx++] = (float)Math.pow(1 + chunkDepths[x][z], strength));
            vertices[idx++] = scale * z;

            // NORMAL, skip these for now
            idx += 3;

            // COLOR
            vertices[idx++] = getColor(;

            // TEXTURE
            vertices[idx++] = (x / (float) width);
            vertices[idx++] = (z / (float) height);

        }
    }
}

/*
 * Calculates the normals
 */
private void calcNormals(short[] indices, float[] verts) {

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i += 3) {
        int i1 = getPositionStart(indices[i]);
        int i2 = getPositionStart(indices[i + 1]);
        int i3 = getPositionStart(indices[i + 2]);

        // p1
        float x1 = verts[i1];
        float y1 = verts[i1 + 1];
        float z1 = verts[i1 + 2];

        // p2
        float x2 = verts[i2];
        float y2 = verts[i2 + 1];
        float z2 = verts[i2 + 2];

        // p3
        float x3 = verts[i3];
        float y3 = verts[i3 + 1];
        float z3 = verts[i3 + 2];

        // u = p3 - p1
        float ux = x3 - x1;
        float uy = y3 - y1;
        float uz = z3 - z1;

        // v = p2 - p1
        float vx = x2 - x1;
        float vy = y2 - y1;
        float vz = z2 - z1;

        // n = cross(v, u)
        float nx = ((vy * uz) - (vz * uy));
        float ny = ((vz * ux) - (vx * uz));
        float nz = ((vx * uy) - (vy * ux));

        // normalize(n)
        float num2 = ((nx * nx) + (ny * ny)) + (nz * nz);
        float num = 1f / (float) Math.sqrt(num2);
        nx *= num;
        ny *= num;
        nz *= num;

        addNormal(indices[i], verts, nx,ny, nz);
        addNormal(indices[i + 1], verts, nx, ny, nz);
        addNormal(indices[i + 2], verts, nx, ny, nz);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (verts.length / VERTEX_SIZE); i++) {
        normalizeNormal(i, verts);
    }
}

// Adds the provided value to the normal
private void addNormal(int vertIndex, float[] verts, float x, float y,
        float z) {

    int i = getNormalStart(vertIndex);

    float rx = (float) ((x * Math.cos(180)) - (y * Math.sin(180)));
    float ry = (float) ((x * Math.sin(180)) + (y * Math.cos(180)));
    x = rx;
    y = ry;
    verts[i] += x;
    verts[i + 1] += y;
    verts[i + 2] += z;
}

/*
 * Normalizes normals
 */
private void normalizeNormal(int vertIndex, float[] verts) {

    int i = getNormalStart(vertIndex);

    float x = verts[i];
    float y = verts[i+1];
    float z = verts[i+2];

    float num2 = ((x * x) + (z * z)) + (y * y);
    float num = (float) Math.sqrt(num2);
    x *= num;
    y *= num;
    z *= num;

    verts[i] = x;
    verts[i + 1] = y;
    verts[i + 2] = z;
}


// Gets the index of the first float of a normal for a specific vertex
private int getNormalStart(int vertIndex) {
    return vertIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 3;
}

// Gets the index of the first float of a specific vertex
private int getPositionStart(int vertIndex) {
    return vertIndex * VERTEX_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: looks like `Gouraud shading` http://www.blog.nathanhaze.com/glsl-phong-and-gouard-shading/

Comment: How are you creating your terrain mesh? Basically, you need your vertex normals to all point out perpendicular to their respective triangles.

Comment: My terrain is created from a an array of floats. Which contains the position, the normals, the color and the terrain coordinates. I then build a model from the mesh. So I should set the normals for each triangle to the same value?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not sure how you originally calculated your normals. If they came from a modeling program, I think you can just set the mesh to flat shading before you export it. But if you are calculating the normals yourself, then take the three vertices of each triangle and use them to calculate the normal that will be common to all three of them.

Comment: Depending on the algorithm you were already using, this may result in more vertices than your original mesh, because vertices won't be able to be shared between adjacent triangles any more, since adjacent triangles won't have identical vertices on their shared edges. With a Gouraud shaded mesh, a vertex can be shared by neighboring triangles because it has the exact same position and normal.

Comment: I've updated the OP with my code for calculating normals. As you can see, the vertices are shared among the triangles. So if I would like to achieve flat shading, I would have to triple the amount of position vertices? Every triangle would have to have 3 unique points sharing the same normals?

Comment: Yes, you cannot share vertices if you want to do this. (Except where two adjacent triangles are coplanar, but that looks unlikely with your algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I changed the way I build the Mesh entirely. Now I build the mesh out of triangles. Here's what it looks like now: [image]. 
it's not yet perfect as there are no diagonal colours but I'm happy with the general look.

Here is how I did it.
I made a new class to hold my variables

```
private Vector3 corner1;
private Vector3 corner2;
private Vector3 corner3;
private Vector3 corner4;
private Vector3 leftNormal;
private Vector3 rightNormal;
private Color color1;
private Color color2;
private Color color3;
private Color color4;
private Vector2 texturePos;
```

and draw them like so:

```
// left triangle
VertexInfo v1 = new VertexInfo();
VertexInfo v2 = new VertexInfo();
VertexInfo v3 = new VertexInfo();

// right triangle
VertexInfo v4 = new VertexInfo();
VertexInfo v5 = new VertexInfo();
VertexInfo v6 = new VertexInfo();

v1.setPos(cell.getCorner1()).setNor(cell.getLeftNormal()).setCol(cell.getColor1()).setUV(cell.getTexturePos());
v2.setPos(cell.getCorner4()).setNor(cell.getLeftNormal()).setCol(cell.getColor1()).setUV(cell.getTexturePos());
v3.setPos(cell.getCorner2()).setNor(cell.getLeftNormal()).setCol(cell.getColor1()).setUV(cell.getTexturePos());

v4.setPos(cell.getCorner3()).setNor(cell.getRightNormal()).setCol(cell.getColor3()).setUV(cell.getTexturePos());
v5.setPos(cell.getCorner2()).setNor(cell.getRightNormal()).setCol(cell.getColor3()).setUV(cell.getTexturePos());
v6.setPos(cell.getCorner4()).setNor(cell.getRightNormal()).setCol(cell.getColor3()).setUV(cell.getTexturePos());

meshBuilder.triangle(v1, v2, v3);
meshBuilder.triangle(v4, v5, v6);
```

I calculate the face normals of the triangles like so:

```
private Vector3 calcNormal(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3) {

    // u = p3 - p1
    float ux = p3.x - p1.x;
    float uy = p3.y - p1.y;
    float uz = p3.z - p1.z;

    // v = p2 - p1
    float vx = p2.x - p1.x;
    float vy = p2.y - p1.y;
    float vz = p2.z - p1.z;

    // n = cross(v, u)
    float nx = ((vy * uz) - (vz * uy));
    float ny = ((vz * ux) - (vx * uz));
    float nz = ((vx * uy) - (vy * ux));

    // // normalize(n)
    float num2 = ((nx * nx) + (ny * ny)) + (nz * nz);
    float num = 1f / (float) Math.sqrt(num2);
    nx *= num;
    ny *= num;
    nz *= num;

    return new Vector3(nx, ny, nz);
}
```